# How to find the location of the thumbnail in the large image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I want to determine the location of this icon in the image. The data is probably like this. Note that the background of the image is changing.
[image]
[image]

I tried opencv's matchTemplate method and aircv's find_template method, but they can't handle the background changes.

If you can let opencv or aircv support looking for a transparent background image, maybe this problem is solved.

Comment: You can change all the transparent pixels to an arbitrary value like 0,0,0 to be counted as a background as a preprocessing step

Comment: Can you add your current results for the template matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Here is docs.https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html